# Can't start docker service after kill it on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos

Started docker this way:

```
# service docker start
```

Want to stop it:

```
# service docker stop
```

Can't. Then `kill -9 ...` all the running processes.

Start again:

```
# service docker start
```

Can't:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  docker.service
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The `journalctl -xe` log:

```
-- The result is failed.
 7月 11 21:17:16 centos75 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
 7月 11 21:17:16 centos75 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
 7月 11 21:17:16 centos75 polkitd[727]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12335:6759586 (system bus name :1.87, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent,
 7月 11 21:17:43 centos75 polkitd[727]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12360:6762295 (system bus name :1.88 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org
 7月 11 21:17:43 centos75 polkitd[727]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12360:6762295 (system bus name :1.88, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent,
 7月 11 21:18:13 centos75 chronyd[732]: Source 121.111.253.121 replaced with 59.106.180.168
 7月 11 21:19:07 centos75 polkitd[727]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12387:6770743 (system bus name :1.89 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org
 7月 11 21:19:07 centos75 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
 7月 11 21:19:07 centos75 dockerd[12404]: time="2017-07-11T21:19:07.768545210-04:00" level=fatal msg="can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: is a directory"
 7月 11 21:19:07 centos75 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 7月 11 21:19:07 centos75 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

And run `docker ps` returned:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Strange.

Comment: so ... `docker` does not show up in `ps`. What makes you think the service is still running ???

Comment: Does docker produce any log files?

Comment: @trs Sorry, the fact is I kill the process by `kill -9 ...` and try to start it again. Then can't. I added the message to the question just now.

Comment: Just remove this: `/var/run/docker.sock`, it's a directory when it shouldn't.

Comment: @rebert Great! That solved the problem! Thank you very much. Can you write it as an answer. I will accept it.